# Display all select option in single line

Tags: html, css

By default only one selected or the default option is displayed in the select box however I want that all the select option to be displayed on the same line and among them the selected option must be highlighted.

Following is my code

```
.selecttodiv{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 3em;    
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

.selecttodiv option{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
}


<select class="selecttodiv">
   <option>I</option>
   <option>II</option>
   <option>III</option>
   <option>IV</option>
   <option>V</option>
   <option>VI</option>
</select>
```

following is the link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6yg4yhyy/

I am able to display all option on the single line but not when selected.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you describe _"all the select option to be displayed on the same line"_ ? , horizontazally ?

Comment: @guest271314 just refer my jsfiddle when you click the select box than all the options are displayed on the single line but as soon as you select one of them than they are all hidden and only the selected option is displayed but I want that irrespective of selected or not all the options must be by default be displayed on the select box and the selected option must be just highlighted.

Comment: It seems the answers suggest styleable wrappers, may I point out that you should put accessibility first here, the well established standard form controls give you a lot of usability that shouldn't be thrown out solely for the sake of being pretty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using `size` attribute on `select` and floating `option`.
On Chrome and FF it was displayed properly. IE (11) doesn't work.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6yg4yhyy/1/)

Maybe it's better to use some select plugin where you can style it as you want..

Comment: can you just remove that scrollbar at the end.

Comment: just add `overflow: hidden;` to select.

Comment: yea, on FF you need to add smaller height. e.g. `height: 30px;`. So as @Justinas said - use some plugin. It's not good to style those elements in this way.

Comment: Yeah it is working on 30px but on my website the elements are displayed as per the size of browser window. Hence I don't want to hardcode any values in px. It would be very nice of you if you propose the solution for the same +1 for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Don't style default form elements. It will cause more issues than you think. Better use some extension that provides stylable html wrapper.

E.g. [select2](https://select2.github.io/), [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selecttodiv').select2({
    width: '190px'
  });
})
```

```css
.select2-results li {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="selecttodiv" multiple="multiple">
  <option>I</option>
  <option>II</option>
  <option>III</option>
  <option>IV</option>
  <option>V</option>
  <option>VI</option>
</select>
```

---

**Update**

Also it may be checkboxes:

```css
.check {
  display: inline-block;
}
span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + span {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span>I</span>
</label>
<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span>II</span>
</label>
<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span>III</span>
</label>
<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span>IV</span>
</label>
<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span>V</span>
</label>
<label class="check">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span>VI</span>
</label>
```

Comment: just refer to @kiwixLV answer we are struck here on removing vertical scrollbar and putting a horizontal scrollbar instead just refer updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6yg4yhyy/4/

Comment: @geeksal I strongly suggest not to style form elements (like checkboxes, select, radio). From my experience it's very hard to put correct style for all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but this project is not for public domain and we are restricted to use only FF and chrome so no issue at all