# display select option as tab

Tags: html, css

I have select box with option which was created in drupal.I want to make the select option in single line. Now oprion is listed one by one.need to list all option without dropdown
[image: Sample]

```css
#edit-type-1{
  width:500px;
}
#edit-type-1 option{
  display:inline;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<select id="edit-type-1" name="type_1" class="form-select">
<option value="All">- Any -</option>
<option value="blogs" selected="selected">Blogs</option>
<option value="case_studies">Case Studies</option>
<option value="whitepapers">Whitepapers</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can't make select option as a single line, but you can make it with list style and relation it with javascript.

Comment: can you give example please

Comment: If you replace it with different HTML code, then you will still have to add script functionality so that it can still perform the task a select field normally would ... it might make much more sense, if you used radio buttons to begin with here, instead of a select field. Techniques how to hide the actual radio button elements, and use the corresponding labels to toggle them (and highlighting the currently “selected” one, if desired), are widely available and can easily be researched.

Comment: Unfortunately, options inside select are a Shadow DOM thus you can't reach them by CSS unless browser gives you special pseudo-classes (--moz etc.). And as far as I know, there is no such thing for options.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194997/display-all-select-option-in-single-line?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

```css
#edit-type-1{
  width:500px;
}
#edit-type-1 option{
  display:inline;
  width:auto;
}
.form-select{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 3em;    
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

.form-select option{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 9em;
    height: 2.5em;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<select name="type_1" class="form-select" size="100" >
<option value="All">- Any -</option>
<option value="blogs" selected="selected">Blogs</option>
<option value="case_studies">Case Studies</option>
<option value="whitepapers">Whitepapers</option>
</select>
```

Please also refer the link - [Select option in single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194997/display-all-select-option-in-single-line)

Answer (score 0):

**Add size in select as shown below :**

```
<select class="form-select" size="3">
  <option value="All">- Any -</option>
  <option value="blogs" selected="selected">Blogs</option>
  <option value="case_studies">Case Studies</option>
  <option value="whitepapers">Whitepapers</option>
</select>
```

**Add the following css:**

```
.form-select{
   display: inline-block;
   height: 3em;    
 }

.form-select option{
   display: inline-block;
   width: auto;
   height: 5px;
   float:left;
 }
```

[[Demo]](https://jsfiddle.net/y23ybhg2/1/)